# Qual a origem da Expressão:"No mês de Março a Dama queima no Palace"

Tags: significado, etimologia, expressões, português-europeu, definição

Qual a origem da Expressão: "No mês de Março a Dama queima no Palace"
Em que século teve origem e por quem?

Ouvia da minha avó, que nasceu em 1916 , na Ilha da Madeira. Ela tinha muitos ditados antigos . Este ela pronunciava com sotaque madeirense, que ficava: "No mês de marce a Dama queima no Palace"

Comment: há pouquissímas referências (para não dizer nenhuma) realizando pesquisas. Eu, particularmente, nunca ouvi essa expressão. Poderia dar mais detalhes? Local onde ouviu? É de uma região específica? Ouviu ou viu em algum livro, jornal, programa de TV?

A única coisa que me remete a Palace (como brasileiro) foi o edifício Palace II que desabou em 1998. Mas isso foi em Fevereiro....

Comment: Ouvia da minha avó, que nasceu em 1916 , na Ilha da Madeira. Ela tinha muitos ditados antigos . Este ela pronunciava com sotaque madeirense, que ficava: "No mês de marce a Dama queima no Palace"

Comment: A minha avó dizia esta expressão quando o mês de Março tinha dias quentes

Comment: Eu aconselho a editar a pergunta e colocar essas informações diretamente, para ficar mais claro. Além disso, retirar a tag portugues-brasileiro...

Comment: Pergunta actualizada. Obrigado pela sugestão.

Comment: CIMend, a informação que adicionaste ficaria melhor no corpo da pergunta e não no título. Eu encontrei "Sol de Março queima a dama no paço". "Paço", claro está, evoluiu, já há séculos, da palavra "palácio".

Comment: Grato pelas respostas. Corpo da pergunta atualizado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variante mais antiga que encontrei desse ditado é de 1627, mas em espanhol, em *Vocabulario e refranes y frases proverbiales* de Gonzalo Correas, no [CORDES da Real Academia Española](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=sol%20de%20marzo&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=1800&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) (clica em “recuperar” para ver):

> El sol de marzo, kema las dueñas del palazio

Em portugués, o mais antigo que encontrei é de 1828, uma alusão ao ditado em [*Besta Esfolada* de José Agostinho de Macedo (vol. 20, p. 9)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=5Cm2kam2rkEC&pg=PA9&dq=%22queima%20a%20dama%20no%20pa%C3%A7o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin2fPk8pjiAhVKbBoKHQPmAI04FBDoAQgpMAA#v=onepage&q=%22queima%20a%20dama%20no%20pa%C3%A7o%22&f=false):

> Na Primavera, que já se sente, e muito bem, **a dez de Março, quando o Sol já queima a Dama no Paço**, o zumbido dos Besouros, e dos Moscardos, já se sente com importunidade.

Naturalmente o ditado poderia já existir há séculos, mas nós só temos o que os nossos tataravós nos deixaram escrito. A [Revista Lusitana de 1892 (vol. 2, p. 126)](https://archive.org/details/RevistaLusitana2/page/n127?q=%22queima%20a%20dama%20no%20pa%C3%A7o%22) traz, “Sol de março queima a dama no paço”.

[*Paço* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/pa%C3%A7o) é o nome que se deu em Portugal ao palácio do rei e de certos senhores, e tem a mesma origem que a palavra *palácio*. Mas no ditado, *paço* provavelmente serve apenas para rimar (imperfeitamente) com *março*. Em Portugal, março é um mês de transição do inverno para a primavera, e alguns dias já aquecem bastante. E muitas pessoas, especialmente entre as mais velhas, estão convictas que o sol em dias quentes de inverno faz mal (mais mal que no verão). Parece ser a isto que o ditado alude. Isto é uma ideia antiga. Em [1716, Raphael Bluteau regista](https://books.google.pt/books?id=badVS0VVqsAC&pg=PA326&dq=%22Sol%20de%20Mar%C3%A7o%20pega%20como%20pegama%C3%A7o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj66O_yoJniAhUtyYUKHd1WAfA4FBDoAQhOMAU#v=onepage&q=%22Sol%20de%20Mar%C3%A7o%20pega%20como%20pegama%C3%A7o%22&f=false) “Sol de Março pega como pegamaço, & fere como maço”. E encontrei em 1632 uma “explicação” deste fenómeno, em espanhol (aportuguesado?), mas escrito em Lisboa por um português, [Antonio de Naiera, Suma Astrologica, (p. 104)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=esWU0j2rj2oC&pg=PA104&dq=%22Mar%C3%A7o%20pega%20como%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLo6Ofi5niAhULyxoKHTeBBHsQ6AEImQEwEQ#v=onepage&q=%22Mar%C3%A7o%20pega%20como%22&f=false):

> Y como el Sol en este tiempo no tenga tanta fuerça que pueda gastar toda la copia de vapores gruessos parece el Aire que recibe tanto calor, que fatiga a todo genero de animal, donde viene el refran, Sol de Março, pega como maço.

Eu só conhecia, “março, marçagão, de manhã inverno, à tarde verão”. O [Bluteau (1716)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=H-NBAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA326&dq=%22Mar%C3%A7o%20Marceg%C3%A3o,%20pela%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisuoSApJniAhVIzBoKHSMRBTY4FBDoAQhIMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Mar%C3%A7o%20Marceg%C3%A3o%2C%20pela%22&f=false) traz “Março Marcegão, pela manhã rosto de caõ, á tarde Verão”. A [Revista Lusitana de 1892](https://archive.org/details/RevistaLusitana2/page/n127?q=%22queima%20a%20dama%20no%20pa%C3%A7o%22) tem uma carrada de variantes destes ditados.